# How to do a Typing animation after another Typing animation finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, callback

I'm currently working on a typing animation but the issue is usually I have a hard time to call a function then when it finishes to call another function, i tried callback but it's usually useless and I need techniques to be able to do that, with animations and with functions please if you can provide explanations. check the codes below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var i;
    var counter = 1;
    var text;
        function typeLike(elem,theText){
            var newString = "";
            text = theText;
            for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
                newString += text.charAt(i);
            }
            $(elem).text(newString);
            counter++;
//            if(counter > text.length){
//                counter = 0;
//            }
        }


    function startTypeLike(elem,str) {
        var randomNum = Math.random()*1000;
        if(counter <= str.length){
            var inter = setTimeout(function(){
                typeLike(elem,str);
                startTypeLike(elem,str);
            },randomNum);
        }
        else{
            $(elem).removeClass("animated");
        }
    }
    startTypeLike(".something","hello all how you doin in this fine day");
    startTypeLike(".other","sup man how you doin in this fine night");
}); // end of ready
```

```css
body,html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.something{
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.animated::after{
    content:"_";
    animation: fade;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-play-state: running;

}
.animated{

}
@keyframes fade{
    0%{opacity:0}
    50%{opacity:1}
    100%{opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="try.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <p class="something animated"></p>
        <p class="other animated"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="try.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to listen to `animationend` and do it using callbacks - Callbacks are not useless, you just don't know how to use them properly.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.. whats animationed and how do i fix this code :p how do I use callbacks properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been great if you had shown us how you tried to implement the callback functionality and why you failed doing so. The code is a bit messy in general, but I left it mostly as it is, just implementing the callback function as a third optional argument in `startTypeLike()` and triggering the second line in the said callback after the first animation. You also have to reset the counter after the first animation, so that the next one will start from the first letter.

**edit:** you'll probably want the blinking "_" for the second line to start only as soon as the typing starts, so I implemented that as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var i;
    var counter = 1;
    var text;
        function typeLike(elem,theText){
            var newString = "";
            text = theText;
            for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
                newString += text.charAt(i);
            }
            $(elem).text(newString);
            counter++;
//            if(counter > text.length){
//                counter = 0;
//            }
        }


    function startTypeLike(elem,str,callback) {
        var randomNum = Math.random()*1000;
        if(counter <= str.length){
            var inter = setTimeout(function(){
                typeLike(elem,str);
                startTypeLike(elem,str,callback); // don't forget to pass the callback function on to the recursive call
            },randomNum);
        }
        else{
            $(elem).removeClass("animated");
            counter = 0;
            callback && callback(); // if a callback function is set, execute it
        }
    }
    startTypeLike(".something","lorem ipsum", function() {
        $('.other').addClass('animated');
        startTypeLike(".other","dolor sit amet");
    });
}); // end of ready
```

```css
body,html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.something{
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.animated::after{
    content:"_";
    animation: fade;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-play-state: running;

}
.animated{

}
@keyframes fade{
    0%{opacity:0}
    50%{opacity:1}
    100%{opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<p class="something animated"></p>
<p class="other"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thankyou so much, but what do you mean by messy, I'm still relatively new. It would be great if you give me some tips and how to be less messy in coding

Comment: It was just a bit hard to grasp why there are two functions and `startTypeLike()` is calling itself recursively. Plus the commented-out section... Would probably be better to encapsulate this functionality into a class of its own - but SO is not the place for writing you a tutorial about that. :) You'll learn and evolve with time, don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

I have not only added callback for end of typing animation, I also reformatted the code to be better, hope it works!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function typeWriter(el, text, onDone) {
        var part = "";
        type(0);

        function type(i) {
            part += text.charAt(i++);
            $(el).text(part);

            if (i < text.length) {
                var randomDelay = Math.random() * 1000;
                setTimeout(function() { type(i); }, randomDelay);
            } else {
                if (onDone) onDone();
            }
        }
    }

    typeWriter(".something", "hello all how you doin in this fine day", function() {
        typeWriter(".other", "sup man how you doin in this fine night");
    });
}); // End of ready
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.something {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.animated::after {
    content: "_";
    animation: fade;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    50% { opacity: 1 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="try.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <p class="something animated"></p>
        <p class="other animated"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="try.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou! this was a great help, i have a question, if (onDone) onDone(); what does this line do ? Sorry but if I dont learn from my mistakes i'll never learn so please it would be awesome if u can explain it to me

Comment: This line actually check if `onDone` is defined, `onDone` is a parameter that is used to invoke callback function, and if `onDone` is set (For example, first call to `typeWriter` have set third parameter to be a function, so when it is done it can call the next statement inside the function. However, the second call to `typeWriter` didn't set the third parameter because there isn't any more `typeWriter` to be called. Therefore it might be undefined and we have to check it)

P/S: vote up if you don't mind =)